# SSD for bootable partition & pagefile

Tags: windows-7, ssd, pagefile

I have heard about problems with SSD used for system partition and paging file on it.
Which brand / type of SSD can be used as system partition safely for 2-3 years?

Remarks:
 - i never turn off my computer.
 - planning to keep user profile on HDD partition.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! We don't do specific shopping recommendations, one reason being that they quickly become outdated. These kinds of questions would be best for our [chat]!

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, I realized that I need to look at the latest recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't give too much about SSD fail propaganda. They can fail as much as HDDs can.

One of the best and reliable SSDs are produced by: (Ordered alphabetically)

- Crucial, m4 series
- Intel, the 320 ones
- Samsung, their 830 series

You shouldn't rely on anything for "safely" 2-3 years, **make regular backups and you are safe** for eternity. Go and buy a SSD to enjoy a totally new user experience.

Check also [this](http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?271063-SSD-Write-Endurance-25nm-Vs-34nm&highlight=34nm) out concerning SSD reliability.

Comment: The m4 series is only reliable using the latest firmware - before it can cause an BSOD every hour (AKA "0x00000f4 error").

Comment: @Robert after 5000 hours yes. One thing to mention is, which is a big + for the m4, how crucial handled that bug.